# I need help inserting a date into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I am struggling to insert a date from a string in the correct format. I just get the error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

My function takes a value which comes in the format `dd/MM/yyyy`

How can I make it the correct format to insert into SQL Server?

```
private object StartDateChecker(String val)
{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(val, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);

    if (val == "") 
       return DBNull.Value;
    else
       val = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    return val;
}
```

Comment: dates dont save format.

Comment: but how can I achieve this? I am struggling

Comment: what part is giving you the error? the ParseExact?

Comment: "how can i make it the correct format to insert into SQL server?" just turn it into a DateTime object and pass it direct to SQL server as a parameter. Pass the DateTime object, not a string. The format is irrelevant at that point. Neither C# nor SQL Server stores dates internally in any human-readable format.

Comment: yes the parseexact part is throwing the error. I am simply just trying to insert a date into a sql database. The string passed into the function is in the format of dd/MM/yyyy and I guess that somehow i need to convert it to MM/dd/yyyy

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work either: new SqlParameter("startingDate", DateTime.ParseExact(StartDateChecker(startDate), "dd/MM/yyyy", null)),

Comment: `new SqlParameter("startingDate", DateTime.ParseExact(startDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", null))` should be perfectly fine, as long as `startDate` is actually a string showing a valid date in dd/MM/yyyy format. That's the only part you haven't mentioned. What value are you passing for `startDate`? If it's null, not a valid date, or not in the right format, then you'll get an error. See https://dotnetfiddle.net/AfpXMj for a working example.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the date to the format `'YYYYMMDD'`.  This will always work in SQL Server.

Or (my preference) convert the date to `'YYYY-MM-DD'`.  This works with almost all internationalization settings -- plus I can read it more easily.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question though, nor does it give a solution with examples...

Answer (score 0):

here is how i made it work:

```
    private object StartDateChecker(String val)
{
    DateTime dt;
    string input = val;
    int index = input.IndexOf(" ");
    if (index > 0)
        input = input.Substring(0, index);

    if (val == "") return DBNull.Value;
    else

       dt = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "dd/MM/yyyy", null); return dt;

}
```